# IMPACT : Can't open /dev/parport0: No such file or directory

Tags: xilinx, jtag

Why the following IMPACT log with JTAG ?

[image: impact]

```
Can't open /dev/parport0: No such file or directory
Can't open /dev/parport1: No such file or directory
Can't open /dev/parport2: No such file or directory
Can't open /dev/parport3: No such file or directory

GUI --- Auto connect to cable...
// *** BATCH CMD : setCable -port auto
AutoDetecting cable. Please wait.
*** WARNING ***: When port is set to auto detect mode, cable speed is set to default 6 MHz regardless of explicit arguments supplied for setting the baud rates
PROGRESS_START - Starting Operation.
 Using windrvr6 driver.
Connecting to cable (Usb Port - USB21).
Checking cable driver.
File version of /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/xusbdfwu.hex = 1030.
File version of /usr/share/xusbdfwu.hex = 1030.
 libusb-driver.so version: 2021-04-18 11:44:26.
Cable connection failed.
Connecting to cable (Parallel Port - parport0).
 libusb-driver.so version: 2021-04-18 11:44:26.
 LPT1 Base Address set from env variable = 0.
 LPT base address = 0000h.
 LPT1 Ecp Address set from env variable = 400.
 ECP base address = 0400h.
LPT port is already in use. rc = FFFFFFFFh
Cable connection failed.
Connecting to cable (Parallel Port - parport1).
 libusb-driver.so version: 2021-04-18 11:44:26.
 LPT2 Base Address set from env variable = 10.
 LPT base address = 0010h.
 LPT2 Ecp Address set from env variable = 410.
 ECP base address = 0410h.
LPT port is already in use. rc = FFFFFFFFh
Cable connection failed.
Connecting to cable (Parallel Port - parport2).
 libusb-driver.so version: 2021-04-18 11:44:26.
 LPT3 Base Address set from env variable = 20.
 LPT base address = 0020h.
 LPT3 Ecp Address set from env variable = 420.
 ECP base address = 0420h.
LPT port is already in use. rc = FFFFFFFFh
Cable connection failed.
Connecting to cable (Parallel Port - parport3).
 libusb-driver.so version: 2021-04-18 11:44:26.
 LPT4 Base Address set from env variable = 30.
 LPT base address = 0030h.
 LPT4 Ecp Address set from env variable = 430.
 ECP base address = 0430h.
LPT port is already in use. rc = FFFFFFFFh
Cable connection failed.
PROGRESS_END - End Operation.
Elapsed time =      2 sec.
Cable autodetection failed.
WARNING:iMPACT:923 - Can not find cable, check cable setup !
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't connect your "cable".

Answer (score 1):

1. ​Xiling ISE is supported only on certain Linux distros. Check the support for your version (your P.20131013 corresponds with Xiling ISE 14.7)
   https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/18419.html

> 14.x
>
> - Windows XP Pro/Windows 7 Pro 32/64-bit/Windows Server 2008 - ISE, ChipScope, EDK, Sysgen, ISIM
> - RHEL WS 5 32/64-bit, RHEL WS 6 32/64-bit - ISE, ChipScope, EDK, ISIM, Sysgen
> - SUSE 32/64-bit - ISE, ChipScope, EDK, ISIM, Sysgen
>
> Note: In the ISE release "supported platforms" are only designated by the major version. However, testing and official support is limited to platform versions that were released early enough prior to the ISE release (about two months) in order that complete testing and compatibility could be ensured.
>
> For example: ISE 14.7 was released in Oct 3, 2013. RHEL was released Nov. 21, 2013. Therefore RHEL 6.5 was never tested or officially supported for ISE 14.7.

2. During installation, you need to follow the steps shown in Xilinx AR# 54381, refer to the section **On Linux**:
   https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/54381.html
3. If the above is correct, your cable is either damaged, bad type or wrong connected

Answer (score 0):

The JTAG cable detection issue is solved by inserting "**source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh**" into $HOME/.bashrc

However, I still have the following CRC error even though IMPACT tool said that bitstream loading is completed.

**WARNING:iMPACT:2217 - Error shows in the status register, CRC Error bit is NOT 0.**

**'1': Programming terminated. DONE did not go high.**

```
'1': Loading file '/home/phung/Downloads/DDR_backup/DDR_Xilinx_ISE/test_ddr3_memory_controller.bit' ...
done.
INFO:iMPACT:1777 - 
Reading /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/spartan6/data/xc6slx16.bsd...
INFO:iMPACT:2257 - Startup Clock has been changed to 'JtagClk' in the bitstream stored in memory,
but the original bitstream file remains unchanged.
UserID read from the bitstream file = 0xFFFFFFFF.
Data width read from the bitstream file = 1.
INFO:iMPACT:501 - '1': Added Device xc6slx16 successfully.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Active mode is BS
GUI --- Auto connect to cable...
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Plugin Version: 2.4.4
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: found 1 device(s).
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: opening device: "JtagSmt1", SN:210203367162
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: User Name: JtagSmt1
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Product Name: Digilent JTAG-SMT1
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Serial Number: 210203367162
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Product ID: 30800151
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Firmware Version: 010A
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: JTAG Port Number: 0
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: JTAG Clock Frequency: 10000000 Hz
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 4/18/21 8:53 PM
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 25000000.
Validating chain...
Boundary-scan chain validated successfully.
'1': IDCODE is '01000100000000000010000010010011'
'1': IDCODE is '44002093' (in hex).
'1': : Manufacturer's ID = Xilinx xc6slx16, Version : 4
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 4/18/21 8:53 PM
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 25000000.
Validating chain...
Boundary-scan chain validated successfully.
'1': Usercode is 'ffffffff'
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 4/18/21 8:53 PM
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 25000000.
Validating chain...
Boundary-scan chain validated successfully.
'1': Reading bootsts register contents...
[0] VALID_0 - ERROR OR END OF STARTUP (EOS) DETECTED                       :         0
[1] FALLBACK_0 - FALLBACK RECONFIGURATION ATTEMPT DETECTED                 :         0
[2] RESERVED                                                               :         0
[3] WTO_ERROR_0 - WATCHDOG TIME OUT ERROR                                  :         0
[4] ID_ERROR_0 - FPGA DEVICE IDCODE ERROR                                  :         0
[5] CRC_ERROR_0 - CYCLIC REDUNDANCY CHECK (CRC) ERROR                      :         0
[6] VALID_1 - ERROR OR END OF STARTUP (EOS) DETECTED                       :         0
[7] FALLBACK_1 - FALLBACK RECONFIGURATION ATTEMPT DETECTED                 :         0
[8] RESERVED                                                               :         0
[9] WTO_ERROR_1 - WATCHDOG TIME OUT ERROR                                  :         0
[10] ID_ERROR_1 - FPGA DEVICE IDCODE ERROR                                 :         0
[11] CRC_ERROR_1 - CYCLIC REDUNDANCY CHECK (CRC) ERROR                     :         0
[12] STRIKE CNT - STRIKE COUNT FOR FALLBACK ATTEMPTS                       :         0
[13] STRIKE_CNT - STRIKE COUNT FOR FALLBACK ATTEMPTS                       :         0
[14] STRIKE_CNT - STRIKE COUNT FOR FALLBACK ATTEMPTS                       :         0
[15] STRIKE_CNT - STRIKE COUNT FOR FALLBACK ATTEMPTS                       :         0
'1': Reading status register contents...
[0] CRC ERROR                                                              :         0
[1] IDCODE ERROR                                                           :         0
[2] DCM LOCK STATUS                                                        :         0
[3] GTS_CFG_B STATUS                                                       :         0
[4] GWE STATUS                                                             :         0
[5] GHIGH STATUS                                                           :         0
[6] DECRYPTION ERROR                                                       :         0
[7] DECRYPTOR ENABLE                                                       :         0
[8] HSWAPEN PIN                                                            :         0
[9] MODE PIN M[0]                                                          :         0
[10] MODE PIN M[1]                                                         :         0
[11] RESERVED                                                              :         0
[12] INIT_B PIN                                                            :         0
[13] DONE PIN                                                              :         0
[14] SUSPEND STATUS                                                        :         0
[15] FALLBACK STATUS                                                       :         0
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 4/18/21 8:53 PM
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 25000000.
Validating chain...
Boundary-scan chain validated successfully.
'1': DNA = '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
INFO:iMPACT - Current time: 4/18/21 8:53 PM
PROGRESS_START - Starting Operation.
Maximum TCK operating frequency for this device chain: 25000000.
Validating chain...
Boundary-scan chain validated successfully.
'1': Programming device...
 LCK_cycle = NoWait.
LCK cycle: NoWait
done.
'1': Reading status register contents...
[0] CRC ERROR                                                              :         1
[1] IDCODE ERROR                                                           :         0
[2] DCM LOCK STATUS                                                        :         0
[3] GTS_CFG_B STATUS                                                       :         0
[4] GWE STATUS                                                             :         0
[5] GHIGH STATUS                                                           :         0
[6] DECRYPTION ERROR                                                       :         0
[7] DECRYPTOR ENABLE                                                       :         1
[8] HSWAPEN PIN                                                            :         0
[9] MODE PIN M[0]                                                          :         0
[10] MODE PIN M[1]                                                         :         0
[11] RESERVED                                                              :         1
[12] INIT_B PIN                                                            :         0
[13] DONE PIN                                                              :         0
[14] SUSPEND STATUS                                                        :         0
[15] FALLBACK STATUS                                                       :         0
WARNING:iMPACT:2217 - Error shows in the status register, CRC Error bit is NOT 0.
INFO:iMPACT:2219 - Status register values:
INFO:iMPACT - 1000 0001 0001 0000 
INFO:iMPACT:579 - '1': Completed downloading bit file to device.
INFO:iMPACT:188 - '1': Programming completed successfully.
 LCK_cycle = NoWait.
LCK cycle: NoWait
INFO:iMPACT - '1': Checking done pin....done.
'1': Programming terminated. DONE did not go high.
PROGRESS_END - End Operation.
Elapsed time =      0 sec.
```